# Is there a shortcut to rotating a 2d adjustment to a normal vector, given the image of the normal after rotation?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, vectors, rotations

I have a 3d normal vector $N$ which is adjusted to $N^\prime=normalize({N+\Delta N})$ with $\Delta N=(0,a,b)$.

$N$ was rotated by a matrix $M$ to give $X=NM$. I also want the normal vector $X^\prime=N^\prime M$.

For computational reasons, $M$ itself is not easily available, but $a$, $b$, and $X$ are.

Can I efficiently compute $X^\prime$ from $\{N, a, b, X\}$, without knowing $M$, and ideally without computing $\Delta N$?

Or, is there an approximation which works for "small" $\Delta N$?

Comment: For an approximation it would be useful to know if $\Delta N$ is small compared to $N$, as well as if you know anything about the rotation matrix.

Comment: $\Delta N$ might change the angle of $N$ by about 45 degrees or so. I could tolerate errors of $\approx 20\%$. The rotation matrix is arbitrary 3d rotation.